# Delphi PostMessage find lpWindowName?

Tags: windows, delphi, window, console-application, postmessage

I have a task to control if application written in Delphi can start or not.

I did not write app that I need to control and at this time, cannot compile its code or change it, so I made other console app to work in background to start and end this application according to the conditions in OS.

I turn off this app with `PostMessage`, but I don't understand how to find what is the `WindowName` of application that I need to shut down.

How can I do that? I have source code of app. I use `"TApplication"` as class name instead. Is this safe to use in Windows?

Comment: Is main window name (caption) unique?

Answer (score 1):

In order to find correct window handle of the application you are looking for you need to know two parameters that you will be sending to `FindWindow` function

**1. window class name**

For most applications sending `WM_CLOSE` message to main form window handle will terminate application.

Application window handle can also be used, but only for applications written in Delphi versions prior to 2007 or for applications that have `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` property set to false.

Note: [Application.MainFormOnTaskbar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar) was introduced in Delphi 2007.

For main form window class name will be main form class name (for instance `'TForm1'`) and for application handle window class name is `'TApplication'`

**2. window name (title)**

This value will depend on whether you will be sending message to application window or main form window.

For application this will be `Application.Title` value or if that is not explicitly set program name will be used.

```
program MyApplication; 

...

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'My Application Title'; 
...
```

If you use main form window value will be main form `Caption` property.

So generally speaking some of following combinations would give you proper results (of course, combined with actual class names and window titles you have)

```
var h: HWND;

  h := FindWindow('TApplication', 'MyApplication');
  h := FindWindow('TApplication', 'My Application Title');
  h := FindWindow('TForm1', 'Form1');
```

While above rules will be generally valid, it is possible that application sets those values in dynamic manner and in that case you would have to use `EnumWindows` instead of `Findwindow`.

Closing application this way is perfectly safe if `window class name & window name` combination uniquely defines application you intend to close. If there are more then one application in the system that satisfy previous condition you may well end up closing wrong one and finding right application may be more complex or application lifetime has to be controlled in another way.

Comment: While this *generally* works for many Delphi apps, it will not work for every Delphi app.  For instance, if an app sets `Application.Title` dynamically, you will not be able to hard-code the name so you will have to hunt for it at runtime, such as with `EnumWindows()`.  And if an app uses `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar=True` (which most modern Delphi apps do nowadays), you should not even be interacting with the `TApplication` window at all, you have to interact with the `MainForm` window instead, and its class name may or may not be unique across multiple apps.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using custom solution for handling messages between applications that does not include `TApplication`, so I was completely unaware that `MainFromOnTaskBar` changes how application responds to outside messages. My code works fine for both. I could do research (actually, I already did some of it) and post more complete solution, but maybe it would be best if you would post your own, more elaborate answer.

Comment: `MainFormOnTaskbar` does a LOT of things (more than it should), but primarily it specifies whether the `TApplication` window or the `TApplication.MainForm` window represents the app to Windows itself.   But it does not change how window messages are received. You can still send messages to the `TApplication` window, but depending on the particular message, that might not be the right window to send to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understood what you are saying, but didn't express myself clearly. In this case termination request is handled differently depending on `MainFormOnTaskbar` and that is what OP is asking for.